# Array.prototype.splice in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

A friend asked me the Ruby best and performant way to achieve the effect of JavaScript's `splice` method in Ruby.
This means no iteration on the Array itself or copies.

"begin at index start, remove length items and (optionally) insert elements. Finally return the removed items in an array." << **This is misleading, see the JS example below.**

http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/41

Quick hack that doesn't have the **optional** substitution:

```
from_index     = 2
for_elements   = 2
sostitute_with = :test
initial_array  = [:a, :c, :h, :g, :t, :m]
# expected result: [:a, :c, :test, :t, :m]
initial_array[0..from_index-1] + [sostitute_with] + initial_array[from_index + for_elements..-1]
```

What's yours?
One line is better.

**Update:**

```
// JavaScript
var a = ['a', 'c', 'h', 'g', 't', 'm'];
var b = a.splice(2, 2, 'test'); 
> b is now ["h", "g"]
> a is now ["a", "c", "test", "t", "m"]
```

I need the resulting 'a' Array, not 'b'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Array#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000219).

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a[2..4] = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :wibble]
a # => [1, 2, :foo, :bar, :baz, :wibble, 6]

# It also supports start/length instead of a range:
a[0, 3] = [:a, :b]
a # => [:a, :b, :bar, :baz, :wibble, 6]
```

As for returning the removed elements, `[]=` doesn't do that... You could write your own helper method to do it:

```
class Array
  def splice(start, len, *replace)
    ret = self[start, len]
    self[start, len] = replace
    ret
  end
end
```

Comment: You still don't have it!  Change `replace` to `*replace`.  Then you get your upvote.

Comment: Given the splice method you wrote I get [:h, :g] as result, which is incorrect, it should be [:a, :c, :test, :t, :m]. Tip: Array#- compares values, which is not good here.

Comment: @kain: Why should it be [:a, :c, :test, :t, :m]? I thought you wanted it to return only the values which were removed? And I'm not using `Array#-`...

Comment: My friend says that Array.prototype.splice will position the cursor on the start index, removes n elements from that index, optionally replace the gap with one instance of something (a symbol, say) and return the **rest** of the array. See my example in original question. Perhaps he's wrong about the JS method?

Comment: @kain, jtbandes's answer, once the `replace` argument is made a varargs :) is faithful to JavaScript's `splice`.  It is supposed to return the removed elements.

Comment: @kain: If you want the array `a`, just use `a` in your code after you do the splice. If you want to return it from the splice, just return `self` instead of `ret`.

Answer (score 3):

First use [`slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000268) to extract the part you want to delete:

```
a   = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ret = a.slice!(2,2)
```

That leaves `[1,2]` in `a` and `[3,4]` in `ret`. Then a simple [`[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000219) to insert the new values:

```
a[2,0] = [:pancakes]
```

The result is `[3,4]` in `ret` and `[1, 2, :pancakes]` in `a`. Generalizing:

```
def splice(a, start, len, replacements = nil)
    r = a.slice!(start, len)
    a[start, 0] = replacements if(replacements)
    r
end
```

You could also use `*replacements` if you want variadic behavior:

```
def splice(a, start, len, *replacements)
    r = a.slice!(start, len)
    a[start, 0] = replacements if(replacements)
    r
end
```