# Splice() not working properly in Ruby Contentful migration?

Tags: ruby, methods, migration, contentful, array-splice

I am attempting to write a Contentful migration that will, in part, remove two elements in an array and replace them with two other elements. Below is the code I am currently using:

```
def up
    with_space do |space|
      content_type = space.content_types.find('trip')

      field = content_type.fields.detect { |f| f.id =='country'}
      validations = field.validations.first.in
      validations.splice(5, 2, 'Puerto-Rico', 'South-Africa')

      content_type.save
      content_type.publish
   end
  end 
end
```

This is the error message I'm getting which appears to indicate that splice() isn't a recognized method. What am I missing here?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `splice' for #<Array:0x00007f9b93c0e618>
Did you mean?  slice
               slice!
               split
```

Comment: Where you get such method?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html Not a method.

Comment: [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-slice) not [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: Does Ruby not a have a method equivalent to splice() in JavaScript? I don't think slice achieves what I need. @SebastianPalma

Comment: [`I don't know`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6892551/5025116) @JakeCatron.